# How to know is prev/next element on sorting of integer value none unique

Tags: mongodb, pagination

I have a list of element in MongoDB with a created_at and nb_likes data like in this case :

```
[{'_id':'1234', 'nb_likes':1, 'created_at':'2010-08-01'},
 {'_id':'1235', 'nb_likes':2, 'created_at':'2010-08-02'},
 {'_id':'1236', 'nb_likes':2, 'created_at':'2010-08-03'},
 {'_id':'1237', 'nb_likes':3, 'created_at':'2010-08-02'},
 {'_id':'1238', 'nb_likes':3, 'created_at':'2010-08-03'}]
```

If I sort this collection by 'nb_likes' the order.

```
db.users.find().sort(['nb_likes':-1])
```

But I want find the previous and next element of document '1236' if I order by 'nb_likes'. If we see the collection, the previous element is document '1235' and next '1237'. But if want do a request to know the previous and next element, I do :

to get previous

```
db.users.find({'nb_likes':{'$gt':2}}).sort(['nb_likes':-1])
```

to get next

```
db.users.find({'nb_likes':{'$lt':2}}).sort(['nb_likes':1])
```

But in this case. I skip all document with nb_likes with 2. So I use '$gte' to have this document

to get previous

```
db.users.find({'nb_likes':{'$gte':2}}).sort(['nb_likes':-1])
```

to get next

```
db.users.find({'nb_likes':{'$lte':2}}).sort(['nb_likes':1])
```

But in this case. the second element is always return. in next and previous element.

If I limit only document with 'created_at' less or more than my document I delete some document with more 'nb_likes' but an old 'created_at'

So I can't know what request I need to do to have the good return.

A good solution is to have the position of this document in my complete list and do a `skip()` and `limit(1)`

I am open to all good solution. I can't know if in SQL we can have the same problem or not.

Comment: why element with id 1235 is 'before' element 1236?

Comment: By default the second sorting is about :created_at you can emulate it with a `sort(['nb_likes':-1],['created_at':1])` It's do by default when two elements order are same

Comment: What is the Mongo query that fetches the ordered list (of documents) you gave as example?

Answer (score 0):

```
var prev = db.users.find({'nb_likes': {$lte: 2}, '_id': {$lt: 1236}}).sort({'nb_likes': -1})
var next = db.users.find({'nb_likes': {$gte: 2}, '_id': {$gt: 1236}}).sort({'nb_likes': 1})
```

*Later edit*

**Generic solution:**

Let's say that you have an ordered list, given/returned by a query (Mongo, SQL, it doesn't matter anyway). The query has a sort clause, that has the form:

```
sort_clause = 
  kw1: order,
  kw2: order,
...
```

where `order` can be DESC or ASC.

I'll define op(order) :

```
<=, if order is DESC
>=, if order is ASC
```

Now, to get the next to element E, you have to construct a query like:

```
SELECT select_clause
WHERE 
   kw1 op(order) E.kw1,
   kw2 op(order) E.kw2,
   ...
ORDER BY sort_clause
OFFSET 1
LIMIT 1
```

Analogue for previous element.

*Later edit 2*

To apply my solution in case the second ordering column is created_at asc:

```
var prev = db.users.find({'nb_likes': {$lte: 2}, 'created_at': {$lte: '2010-08-03'}}).sort({'nb_likes': -1, 'created_at': -1}).skip(1).limit(1)
var next = db.users.find({'nb_likes': {$gte: 2}, 'created_at': {$gte: '2010-08-03'}}).sort({'nb_likes': 1, 'created_at': 1}).skip(1).limit(1)
```

Comment: can't work if you have a nb_likes greater than 2 and an id lesser than document_id. So you can have some bad result :(

Comment: Then what's your sort criteria? How do you decide that element X is prev to element Y, if X.nb_likes = Y.nb_likes?

Comment: It's a second sort to do the difference, created_at by example. But I can't do the query about the second element only if the element is equal

Comment: Dude, you down voted my answer for nothing, you just don't understand how ORDER BY clause works :). If you (ORDER BY A, B), if will arrange/sort elements E1 and E2 by column B *ONLY IF* E1.A == E2.A

Comment: btw (offtopic), created_on/created_at is redundant in mongo collections, you can just use _id, as you don't have to use another index ;) http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs

Comment: I know about the created_at already in ObjectId. But you solution doesn't work if the next element has less nb_likes and a 'created_at' more. By example an output a list like :  {'_id':'1234', 'nb_likes':1, 'created_at':'2010-08-04'},
 {'_id':'1235', 'nb_likes':2, 'created_at':'2010-08-03'},
 {'_id':'1236', 'nb_likes':2, 'created_at':'2010-08-02'}, In this case you have no return :(

Comment: But.. how is the output list created? By what query?